# Android, get data from web and update UI (Multi-threading and MVC design pattern)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, okhttp

Currently developing a weather application . I wanna strictly observe 2 rules:

1. MVC Design pattern
2. Multithreading when I deals with network.

The problem is combining these things into a whole, here are parts of my code:

**Weather Class (represent a Weather object)** :

```
public class Weather {
    private int mTimeInSeconds;
    private String mTimeZone;
    private int mTemperature;
    private String mSummary;

    public Weather(int timeInSeconds, String timeZone, int temperature, String summary) {
        mTimeInSeconds = timeInSeconds;
        mTimeZone = timeZone;
        mTemperature = temperature;
        mSummary = summary;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(mTimeZone));
        Date dateTime = new Date(mTimeInSeconds * 1000);
        String timeAsString = formatter.format(dateTime);
        return timeAsString;
    }

    public int getTemperature() {
        return mTemperature;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return mSummary;
    }
}
```

Worker Class (do all "dirty" work):

```
public class Worker {
    private final OkHttpClient mClient = new OkHttpClient();
    private String apiKey = "Secret!11";
    private double latitude = 37.8267;
    private double longitude = -122.423;
    private String forecastUrl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/"
                                    +apiKey
                                    +"/"
                                    +latitude
                                    +","
                                    +longitude;

    public void getCurrentWeather() throws Exception {
        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url(forecastUrl)
                            .build();

        mClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                Log.v(MainActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    JSONObject weatherData = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    JSONObject currentlyWeather = weatherData.getJSONObject("currently");
                    Log.v(MainActivity.TAG, currentlyWeather.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.v(MainActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Based on my understanding of MVC I put all data and logic around that data in Model (Worker and Weather classes). I wanna to achieve something like this in

**MainActivity.java:**

```
...
Worker mWorker = new Worker();
Weather mWeather = mWorker.getWeatherData();
...
```

2 questions:

1. Is this the correct design of MVC? (I mean, that all code which somehow work with data separated from the controller which only update view's)
2. If yes, how I can implement this? I need to return Weather object 
   from Worker, **but** I can't do this because it's happen on separate thread, I wanna return Weather object to main thread, but have no idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As far as I know, your **M**odel is your `Weather.java` class, your MainActivity (and additional added Activities) are your **C**ontroller and
   finally your `layout.xml` files are your  **V**iew. So AFAIK yes,
   this is correctly implemented followed the **MVC** pattern.
2. It sounds as your `Worker.java` class should be of an `AsyncTask`
   implementation.

An example using `AsyncTask` (This is just a stub implementation, see the links below to see fully working examples):

```
private class WorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Network calls go here. This will be done in the background, 
        //in a separate thread

        //Finally, you return your result here to onPostExecute
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //This method runs on the main UI thread. Here you update your UI o return data to your caller class.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Called before execution
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        //If you want to update your UI with your current progress, that code goes here
    }
}
```

Finally, you will execute your AsyncTask like this:

```
new WorkerTask().execute("your_url");
```

More examples using AsyncTask [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/asynctask/android-asynctask-example/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) and [here](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html).
Official documentation is found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

**Regarding AsyncTask and the MVC design pattern**

A downside of this is that the AsyncTask has to be implemented in your MainActivity (or wherever you want to make use of it) which contradicts the MVC design.

A solution to this would be to create a "HTTP caller class" which does the network calls, and which is called in your `AsyncTask doInBackground` method.

Using this approach, you would be good to go. You would have your controller (MainActivity) executing the AsyncTask (but not doing any actual network calls in MainActivity) creating a new HttpCallerClass, then calling a method which handles the networking. Hence, MVC is preserved.

Comment: Thx for the reply, I know about AsyncTask and that's why I don't use it. It breaks MVC design pattern. If I understand correctly your idea of implementation:
Implement AsyncTask in MainActivity class, but, doInBackground simply calls method from Model (which does all network-based work behind the scenes).
If yes - can this be considered as a correct solution for MVC design pattern?

Comment: See my edit, I address that problem and propose a solution. @VitalySulimov